# Handling an expression outside of a repeat in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone please let me borrow your eyes for a second because this has to be some dumb little nuance I'm missing here...?

So as example, within an ng-repeat I pull out a value and throw an inline expression at it like this (in this example, just changing some text color based on how many days old the value is):

**EDIT* - scope.item doesn't mean anything in particular, I just edited the verbiage a little to get rid of any identifying names for the sake of an internet example.**

```
ng-class="{
            'green-text':{{daysSinceToday(item.theItemDate) <= 20}},
            'orange-text':{{daysSinceToday(item.theItemDate) > 20 && daysSinceToday(item.theItemDate) < 30}},
            'red-text':{{daysSinceToday(item.theItemDate) >= 30}}
           }">
```

Which works splendidly, except then when I'm outside of the scope of the ng-repeat and try something similar but using just `[0]` on the item index like you see, then I can still get the value to display, but it doesn't seem to care about the ng-class expressions at all and instead just grabs the first class listed in the ng-class no matter what the value is.

So if I do something like this OUTSIDE of the ng-repeat;

```
ng-class="{
            'someclass':{{daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) <= 20}},
            'anotherclass':{{daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) > 20 && daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) < 30}},
            'yetanotherclass':{{daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) >= 30}}
           }">
```

It just doesn't seem to care, which is weird because if I just put it in there raw like;

```
{{daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate)}}
```

Without the expression, it DOES give me the correct value but seems to ignore the ng-class. What am I missing here? I must be tired, and this monday should end on a high note lol. Thanks!

Comment: accessing scope.item[0] implies you added an array named "item" to the scope.  I betcha a nickel your array is named "items"

Comment: nah I just changed the verbiage a little to ditch any identifying info, just think of the words scope.item as just placeholders for an example. I haven't been at the angular thing very long obviously.

Comment: the problem in your code--from my vantage--is that you're saying `scope.item[0]` when you mean `item[0]`

Comment: ok, I guess you're going to have to show us more of the code  -- can you give us the ng-repeat that does work, so we can see what data it's reading from?  (@gonzofish is right as well that the 'scope.' doesn't belong inside the template, if you are including it.  Which is a mistake I make often enough that I am tempted at times to put scope.scope = scope in my directives...)

Comment: ugh, never mind, we're all overlooking the obvious.  See answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah! File under I Blame Lack Of Caffeine, you want:

```
ng-class="{
            'someclass':daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) <= 20,
            'anotherclass':daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) > 20 && daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) < 30,
            'yetanotherclass':daysSinceToday(scope.item[0].theItemDate) >= 30
           }">
```

...no curlies necessary inside the ng-class.

(The rules for when you need {{}} and when you don't are <strike>arbitrary and confusing</strike> easy to overlook, as demonstrated quite clearly here)

Comment: Obviously I'm still learning the caveats of the angular/html/css stuff after living in my xaml/.net world too long haha. Seriously, thanks for the slice of humble pie..

Comment: heh, I've been using Angular daily for two years and STILL get hung up on  stuff like this.  Thank god for the easy bugs, otherwise we'd be stuck with nothing but the hard ones

Comment: You **never** use curly braces for Angular's directives, with the exception of `ngHref` and `ngSrc(set)`. But those are replacements for native attributes only to avoid incorrect requests.

Comment: Following @zeroflagL's note, if something looks like JavaScript, curly braces are not to be used. In this case, `ng-class` takes a JavaScript map between class names and their conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't be accessing it as `scope.item[0]`.
I am not sure what is the variable you are iterating in `ng-repeat` but, assuming you are using something like `items`, you should access it just with `items[0].whatever(...`